# g++ optimizing arihmetic expression with trivial terms (zero-product terms)

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

I writing mathematical code with a complicated arithmetic expression that is being used with varying types of inputs, but for the purpose of hyper-optimization AND readability, I want to use it as a macro rather than a function.  However, I'm having trouble getting g++ (4.9.2) to optimize in a way I would think is obvious and need help.

The arithmetic operation of interest is in only one location, but the rub is that there are numerous permutations to the input variables. That is, the equation variables can be either a singleton or an array.  For the purpose of conserving memory and CPU cache, I want to code for each variation (i.e. array and singleton input).  Another element of the problem is that some terms of the equation drop out under certain conditions variables might not just be a singleton, but known *a priori* to be exactly 0 for certain instances, thus causing terms of the equation to be trivial.

Consider the following simplified, illustrative example

```
float a[128],b[128],c[128],d[128],e[128],r[128];
float a0, b0, c0, d0, e0;
...
#define ITERATE for (int n=1; n<N; n++)
#define THE_EQ(A,B,C,D,E,F) r[n] = A*(B-C) + D*E + F
...
switch(condition) {
   case 1: ITERATE THE_EQ(a[n],b[n],c[n],d[n],e[n],0); break;
   case 2: ITERATE THE_EQ( a0 ,b[n],c[n],d[n],e[n],0); break;
   case 3: ITERATE THE_EQ(  0 ,b[n],c[n],d[n],e[n],0); break;
   case 4: ITERATE THE_EQ(a[n],b[n],c[n],d[n],e[n],0); break;
   case 5: ITERATE THE_EQ( a0 ,b[n],c[n], d0 ,e[n],0); break;
   case 6: ITERATE THE_EQ(  0 ,b[n],c[n],  0 ,e[n],1); break;

   ....
} // switch
```

The real code has a more complex equation/macro and has many more permutations of input variable, but the above code is my test of g++ compiler/optimizer.  What I'm finding is that g++ is not optimizing as I had hoped.  That is, g++ is not dropping, when appropriate, the trivial arithmetic operations.

For example, in case 3, I expect the final microcode free of any `b[n] - c[n]` related operation.  And for case 6, I expect elements in array `r[n]` to be simply set to `1`, with no arithmetic operations at all.  Unfortunately, neither is the case. :(

The optimizations that does occur are the AVX vectorization and using `VXORPS` to generate the zero value.  But with the optimally generated 0, g++ still goes thru with the trival `0*(b[n]-c[n])` and `0*e[n]` operations.

Witness:

```
; case 6: ITERATE THE_EQ(0,b[n],c[n],0,e[n],1); break;
0x400778    vxorps xmm1,xmm1,xmm1                     ; generate 0
...
0x4007a0    vmovaps ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax*1]
0x4007a5    vmulps ymm2,ymm1,YMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax*1]  ; 0*e[n]
0x4007aa    vsubps ymm0,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rcx+rax*1]  ; b[n]-c[n]
0x4007af    vmulps ymm0,ymm0,ymm1                     ; (b[n]-c[n])*0
0x4007b3    vaddps ymm0,ymm0,ymm2                     ; 0*(b[n]-c[n])+0*e[n]
0x4007b7    vaddps ymm0,ymm0,ymm3                     ; ....+1
0x4007bb    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax*1],ymm0
0x4007c0    add    rax,0x20
0x4007c4    cmp    rax,0x200
0x4007ca    jne    0x4007a0 <main()+128>
```

Obviously, this is NOT optimal.  Is there a technique (via PRAGMA or compile flag) that will encourage g++ drop those trivial arithmetic operations?    Or is there another method, other than hardcoding 60+ different expressions, to get to my desired level of optimization.

Command is

> g++-4.9 -Wall -fexceptions -O3 -g -march=corei7-avx main.cpp

with g++ 4.9.2

Comment: Marc Glisse's answer is likely the reason you are not seeing the elimination of expressions multiplied by a constant zero but as a side note, your premise that macros are the way to achieve readability and optimization in C++ is wrong. You should really consider using inline functions or templates (depending on the details of your problem) rather than macros for this sort of thing in C++. A modern compiler will generally do as good or better a job of optimization and the resulting code will be more readable and more debuggable.

Comment: Also, in your macro, it's unsafe not to put parentheses around macro parameters. Example, I would say `#define THE_EQ(A,B,C,D,E,F) r[n] = (A)*((B)-(C)) + (D)*(E) + (F)`. Otherwise, you're at the mercy of precedence mistakes.

Comment: @Dunlavey. I'm aware of the issue you note.  My real code already includes nesting each parameter in paraphrases.  I left it out of the test code for expediency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* Maybe fold x * 0 to 0.  The expressions aren't the same
   when x is NaN, since x * 0 is also NaN.  Nor are they the
   same in modes with signed zeros, since multiplying a
   negative value by 0 gives -0, not +0.  */
```

The optimization in gcc is guarded by a few conditions. `-ffast-math` is the easiest way to convince gcc that you do not care about those cases.

Comment: -ffast-math did it! thanks.  After I posted the question, the issue of 0*NaN and 0*Inf had occurred to me, so I tried -ffinite-math-only....with no luck.  Obviously, I had forgotten about signed zeros.

Comment: PS -ffast-math was definitely the easiest, but the combo of -fno-signed-zeros and -ffinite-math-only is also sufficient to do the trick